# HTML5 with .NET backend App, compatible with both standalone Windows and Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, azure

I need to design an HTML 5 responsive, and simple app that should work on both internal Win server and on Azure.Our Client wants to check out Azure but maybe later he will want this app to be on its own on premise servers. Our Developers are almost all .NET back ends, with basic knowledge in HTML 5, Javascript, Jquery, and bootstrap. We accepted the challenge because the project is tiny and interesting, the point is, is possible to have 1 project that can be deployed to azure or IIS with no problem? and what kind of project should we create? I think that a simple asp.net project with some web methods and js will do the job, but I don't know if it will work on azure too. Back n 2010 I did something that way but now I am not sure it's still valid

Important: the web application should be able to query oracle on premise server, via web service but not sure if take azure service bus or azure vpn

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you build your application. I have built applications in the past that works both on-premise and on Azure. As long as you don't access any Azure specific features, there's no problem to deploying the web application project to an on-premise IIS.

If you use Azure-specific features or services from Azure, such as Azure SQL DB, you have to built an on-premise version. In my case it was simple as changing the connection string and the rest was done by Entity Framework, but you can use an IoC container, such as Unity, to change your implementation based on the environment you're running on. If the Azure environment is available (check through `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable`) you resolve the Azure-specific implementation of some features and if not the on-premise implementation. In most cases that are just a few dependencies, for example if you use a worker role on Azure and a Windows Service on-premise.